# What is more efficient: loading and adding a nib or creating the custom controls programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios, performance, user-controls, custom-controls

I'm trying to find out which approach is better to create the same controls in a view.
Let's say that I have a UIview which I want to display 100 custom controls in it.
each custom control contains 2 uiImageView and 3 uiLabel.
Now there are 2 approaches to do that:

1. Create a nib with this controls, its file owner is UIView and load it 100 times with InitWithFrame.
   So I have 100 uiViews, with 5 controls each = 600 uicontrols
2. create the controls programmatically, all on the same uiview.
   So I have 5 * 100 = 500 uicontrols.

So it seems that approach 2 is better in memory consumption, but is it really?
and what about loading time of each approach? which is better?

Thank you

Comment: @Till Before the measuring, comes the theory...

Comment: I'll second this.  When you have high quality tools like Instruments at your disposal, it's very quick to find out.

My gut instinct is that the difference between two approaches is going to negligible compared the cost of actually constructing and rendering the initial state of the 500 views.

Comment: Assuming the difference is not great, if I was choosing between these two, my question would be which code is more easy to follow, maintain, and therefore more bug resistant. Ultimately this leads to the best apps IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that a third approach is the best:
Use UITableView to create the view.
That way you'll use the reuse abilities of the uitable.
The 2 approaches suggested in the question will create a memory warning at some point if you don't reuse the controls (as uitable reuse its rows).

Answer (score 1):

The second approach to create the controls is faster.  Both solutions have to create controls, but the first approach has the overhead of parsing the NIB file.  The question is: how much faster is the second approach.  And: is the first approach so slow that it will impact your particular application?

Here is a good code sample for timing short-duration events: http://zpasternack.blogspot.com/2012/07/high-resolution-timing-in-cocoa.html

Comment: Isn't loading the same nib over and over will be easier for the Cocoa framework, since it's already knows the memory structure needed? I'm thinking if it has similarity to querying a DB with a stored procedure or with a constructed query, where for the first approach the DB can construct a statistics and optimization and the second not.

Comment: I know of no optimizations that are performed when the same NIB is loaded repeatedly.  Yes, it is possible.  But I don't know of any logic in iOS that supports this.  AFAIK, it has to re-parse the NIB every time and create the controls every time.  And I agree with the others who commented on your original question.  If it's important: measure, don't guess.